# Why do functions with even powers of x not have inflection points?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation

Like, for example taking the derivative twice of the infinite sum of $$x^{2n+2}/(2n+1)$$ we get a function that cannot ever have inflection points, but why?

Comment: Because the second derivative of that function never changes sign..? Whether that's a satisfactory answer depends on how you conceptualise inflection points, I suppose.

Comment: Note though that a function "with only even powers of $x$" absolutely can have an inflection point. E.g. $f(x) = x^4 - x^2$.

Comment: Infinite sum? Notice that $$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+1} = x\  \text{arctanh}(x)$$
This is an infinite sum.

Comment: @prets that makes perfect sense! I just thought that if the second derivative equaled zero then we had an inflection point, so after taking the derivative twice I realized that x could still equal zero, meaning that we would have one at x = 0, no?

Comment: @Kleinbottle but how does that prove that there are no inflection points? I'm sorry I don't perfectly follow.

Comment: If by inflection point you mean a *change* in concavity, then the function $f(x) = x^4$ has none. It's true the second derivative is zero at $x = 0$, but it is positive on either side of it.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense when coming from the definition of an inflection point, It was just messing with my head because whenever the second derivative is 0, we have inflection points (or so I was taught in my BC class), but I should really think more about it on my own lol.

Comment: The second derivative indicates concavity. When it is negative, the curve is concave-down. When it is positive, the curve is concave-up. An inflection point is a point where the curve changes concavity. So at an inflection point, the second derivative must swap from being negative to being positive, or vice versa. But if the second derivative is continuous (true for all well-behaved functions, but not guaranteed), then it can only swap signs by passing through $0$. So it is $0$ at inflection points. But it being $0$ does not guarantee you have an inflection point.

Comment: (cont.) This is because the 2nd derivative doesn't have to change signs when it goes to $0$. It can approach $0$ from one side, then leave $0$ on that same side. This is exactly what $12x^2$ does at $x = 0$, which is why $y=x^4$ has no inflection point at $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  By that logic, wouldn't any function with an even power of two have zero inflection points?

Comment: No function of the form $f(x) = Ax^{2n}$ has inflection points. But I'm not sure what you mean by "any function with an even power of two". As prets has already pointed out $f(x) = x^4 - x^2$ has inflection points - at $\frac 1{\sqrt 6}$ and at $\frac {-1}{\sqrt 6}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Is there any way to check for that other than just having graph knowledge? For instance, $x^2$ also doesn't have any inflection points, because it never changes concavity, no? 
So the thing I was getting at was that if it is just a variable to the 2n power, it has no inflection points, but is that wrong?

Comment: It has no inflection points. $x^4$ has no inflection points. $x^6$ has no inflection points. $x$ raised to any even power will not have inflection points. Why? Take the second derivatve. It is a multiple of $x$ raised to the next lower even power. It is equal to $0$ at $x = 0$, which is the only *candidate* to be an inflection point. But, because the power is still even, the second derivative is positive on both sides of that point. Which means it has the same concavity, and $x = 0$ is not an inflection point. Which is also obvious from the graph.

Comment: But $x^4 - x^2$ is not an even power of $x$. It is the difference between two such powers, but that is not the same thing as actually being an even power of $x$ itself. The reasoning I used to show $x$ raised to an even power has no inflection points does not apply to this function. Its second derivative is $12x^2 - 2$, which is $0$ at $x =\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt 6}$ and the second derivative changes sign at each of these points. Thus the original function changes concavity at each. They are both inflection points.